# jQuery update method then set options

Tags: jquery, html

Problem with this plugin: http://slideme.luigiferraresi.it/

I have setup my html exactly the way it can or should be, I am using sections within the ul instead of list items "li". The documentation says for the plugin you can use a div with sections or use a ul with li. I have tried both and same bug. Basically with the script below and its options, the plugin doesn't seem to count the current slides in the html and by default adds one list item that wraps around both my slide items, that being my section elements. I have tried some of the methods list in the documentation one being "update". This fixes my problem, but then I have no idea how to use this method and use the option i need below e.g. touch: true, pagination etc

jQuery:

```
jQuery('#slider').slideme({
    pagination: 'numbers',
    touch: true,
    swipe: true,
    arrows: true,
    autoslide: false,
    itemsForSlide: 2,
    labels: {
        next: 'next',
        prev: 'prev'
    }
});
```

jQuery that fixes the li wrapper around both sections, I dont know how to use this code with the above so it updates first then loads my options:

```
jQuery('#slider').slideme('update');
```

HTML:

My current html in the code editor:

```
<div id="slider">
<div class="slideme">
    <article class="">
    </article>

    <article class="">
    </article>
</div>
</div>
```

HTML being displayed on inspect:

```
<div id="slider">
<div class="slideme">
  <li class="current">

    <article class="">
    </article>

    <article class="">
    </article>

  </li>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help appreciated thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask JQuery to wait for the page to load before changing the options :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider').slideme({
        pagination: 'numbers',
        arrows: true,
        autoslide: false,
        labels: {
            next: 'next slide',
            prev: 'prev slide'
        }
    });
});
```